# Warning: strpos() expects at most 3 parameters, 23 given in page.php on line 9

Tags: php, strpos

1.List item

```
if (strpos($page_name_ulter, 'dissertation' ||  $page_name_ulter, 'vendor' || $page_name_ulter, 'js' || $page_name_ulter, 'css' || $page_name_ulter, 'bootstrap' || $page_name_ulter, 'CI3Xmuqx6MsCFcJf2wod6s0P9Q' ||   $page_name_ulter, 'vendor' || $page_name_ulter, 'vendor' || $page_name_ulter, '=' ||   $page_name_ulter, 'essay?' ||   $page_name_ulter, 'input' ||   $page_name_ulter, 'main.js' || $page_name_ulter, 'main' || $page_name_ulter, 'php/js' || $page_name_ulter, '/' || $page_name_ulter, '.js' || $page_name_ulter, 'rating' || $page_name_ulter, 'intlTelInput' || $page_name_ulter, '.min' || $page_name_ulter, 'images') !== false) { return false; }
```

Comment: It means exactly what it states. There are 23 parameters passed to the strpos function, it expects 3. Your example additionally states, that you can't format your code properly, even when you post it to a QA site and seeking dubugging help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `strpos()` will not work with multiple `&& OR ||` conditions, So you need to add `)`, `strpos` and `!== false` like below:

```
if (strpos($page_name_ulter, 'dissertation') !== false ||  strpos($page_name_ulter, 'vendor') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'js') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'css') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'bootstrap') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'CI3Xmuqx6MsCFcJf2wod6s0P9Q') !== false ||strpos($page_name_ulter, 'vendor') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'vendor') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, '=') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'essay?') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'input') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'main.js') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'main') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'php/js') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, '/') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, '.js') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'rating') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'intlTelInput') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, '.min') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'images') !== false) { return false; }
```

For more details about function :- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Note:- More better solution is using `preg_match()`

Check manual for it:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

you have do it like this

```
if (strpos($page_name_ulter, 'dissertation') !== false ||  strpos($page_name_ulter, 'vendor')!== false  and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the basic sentance of **strpos()** function.

*strpos(string,find,start)*

But in your case you pass only condition in **strpos()** function.
Thats wrong..

Check This

```
if (strpos($page_name_ulter, 'dissertation') !== false ||  strpos($page_name_ulter, 'vendor') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'js') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'css') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'bootstrap') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'CI3Xmuqx6MsCFcJf2wod6s0P9Q') !== false ||strpos($page_name_ulter, 'vendor') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'vendor') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, '=') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'essay?') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'input') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'main.js') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'main') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'php/js') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, '/') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, '.js') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'rating') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'intlTelInput') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, '.min') !== false || strpos($page_name_ulter, 'images') !== false) { return false; }
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP `strpos` doesn't work with multiple ( OR / || ) condition in single `strpos` function.

As per docs : `strpos` Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

To make it work you need multiple `strpos` with `IF` Statement

```
if (
strpos($page_name_ulter,'dissertation') !== false || 
strpos($page_name_ulter,'vendor') !== false
) {

echo 'Founded';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As someone else mentioned, you should know what `strpos` expects, just take a look here: [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
The following suggestions is to reduce the many function calls to strpos

Because you have so many different values, i would suggest other methods. If your string only contains the value you're searching for, i would go for an array and the condition could use `if (in_array($ultravariable, $arrayWithPossibleValues)) { }`
`$arrayWithPossibleValues` should then be the array holding wach value you are searching for.

If the string you're searching in (the ultra variable) does indeed hold more data, but you just need to check that it starts with your different values, then i would go for a `preg_match`.

`if ( preg_match("/^(value1|value2|value3)/", $ultravariable)) { }`
Here you would replace your possible values with value1, value2 etc, and remember to separate them with `|`.

Hope this helps